# Как в simple-html-dom получить реальный URL?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Например, эта ссылка в браузере открывается "как есть". https://eda.ru/recepty/vypechka-deserty/brauni-brownie-20955

Но если поменять число в ссылке, то при открытии страницы ссылка меняется на нужную сама собой. Например, если поставить 20954:

https://eda.ru/recepty/vypechka-deserty/brauni-brownie-20954

То открывается другое блюдо, хотя изначально в ссылке написано "Брауни" из группы "Выпечка и десерты". Я этим воспользовался, когда писал скрейпер на Jsoup в Java - там я просто в цикле проходил и подсовывал в ссылку числа, все происходило само. Но сейчас пришлось переписывать его на PHP и в Simple Html Dom нет этой функции... Я так понял, перед передачей ссылки в функцию `load_file` нужно достать "настоящий" URL. Как это сделать?

Например, вот этот код

```
$html -> load_file("https://eda.ru/recepty/vypechka-deserty/brauni-brownie-20955");
$link = $html -> find("link", 0);
$exploded = explode("/", $link->href);
$category = $exploded[4];
echo $category;
```

Работает. Но если поменять на 20954, то вылетает еррор пицот. А если поменять на полный URL, то работает

Comment: Можно пример реализации? Я не пойму зачем ссылка реальная если на PHP можно так же менять цифры и парсить спокойно.

Comment: @Yaroslav Molchan, обновил вопрос

Comment: 404 там у вас вылетает,   а не 500, а если быть точнее то 301-301-404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть подозрения что `Simple HTML DOM` не умеет ходить по редиректам, по этому я рекомендовал бы вам обходной путь, простым `curl` вы забираете данные и потом кормите их парсеру через `str_get_html`, у меня всё работает, вот пример:

```
$url = "https://eda.ru/recepty/vypechka-deserty/brauni-brownie-2093"; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

$html = str_get_html($result);
$link = $html->find("link", 0);
$exploded = explode("/", $link->href);
$category = $exploded[4];
echo $category;
```

Это всего лишь пример, лучше потом это всё разбить на функции для удобства использования.

Comment: вместо подозрений лучше бы открыли `Simple HTML DOM` и посмотрели каким образом он получает данные. Внутри используется `file_get_contents`, который в принципе сам по себе умеет обрабатывать редиректы. Проблема тут не в редиректах, а в куках по видимости.

Comment: @teran, в куках? Стоп, а как тогда Jsoup с этим справляется?

Comment: @Flippy мб и не в куках. но `file_get_contants` успешно обрабатывает 301е редиректы по умолчанию, сервер отфильтровывает его по какому то другому принципу. Куки я тоже пытался прописать в хэдэры, но не помогло.

Comment: @teran, Я сейчас попробую изучить код Jsoup.. Там метод `Jsoup.connect(url)` есть

Comment: @Flippy Проще время не тратить а загружать страницу как предложено через cURL и кормить готовый HTML парсеру. Чисто ради академического разве что. Про куки я думал, что мб `file_fet_contents` не принмиает куки и не передает их со следующим запросом. На основании этого сервер и отправляет его в лес. Заголовки ответов при использовании можно посмотреть через `print_r($http_response_header);`, там видно что два раза редиректит сначала, потом 404 выдает.

Comment: @teran, пробовал.. Не работает парсер после этого, другой html приходит. Кстати как вывести html код скриптом?

Comment: @teran, о нет! Все работает, я ошибся ))) просто я забыл что использовал юзер агент другой, выставил его курлу и все заработало. Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: @Flippy а что за юзер агент?

Comment: @teran, `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Q415 Build/MOB31K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Mobile Safari/537.36` я просто на андроиде сначала писал парсер а сайт на мобилы по разному контент отдает, вот я и меняю его на этот на бекенде